# Subclass does not inherit its functionality

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, compiler-errors, subclass

I am trying to create a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`, but I cant call its original functionality such as for example `itemSize` and I get the error saying

> Property 'itemSize' not found on object 'SubClass *'

What am I missing?

My code looks like this.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SubClass : UICollectionViewLayout

@end
```

.m

```
#import "SubClass.h"

@implementation SubClass

- (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *answer = [self layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    for(int i = 1; i < [answer count]; ++i) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentLayoutAttributes = answer[i];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *prevLayoutAttributes = answer[i - 1];
        CGFloat maximumSpacing = 20.0f;
        CGFloat origin = CGRectGetMaxX(prevLayoutAttributes.frame);
        if(origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize.width) {
            CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = origin + maximumSpacing;
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

@end
```

Comment: The `itemSize` property is part of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, not `UICollectionViewLayout`. But the code you posted doesn't mention `itemSize`. Show us the code that contains the error.

Comment: Also, the code you posted calls `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` recursively, so even if it compiled, you'd get a stack overflow at runtime. You probably meant to say `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect]`.

Comment: Doh! how silly of me, I was too tired yesterday. I changed it to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` now it works fine. I also changed it to super, and not self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inherited from the wrong class. The `itemSize` property is part of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, not `UICollectionViewLayout`.

Also, you probably want to call `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect]`. Sending that message to `self` will cause a stack overflow due to unbounded recursion.